# How to extract active user email address from Django

Tags: python, django

I want to extract a list of active users email addresses from Django's Home › Authentication and Authorization › Users page and put it into a template. Can someone help me achieve this?

So far I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

if User.is_active:
    emails = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
```

Comment: Are you asking for help with the query, or the view itself? And if the view, what aspects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how to get a list of email addresses for active users:

```
emails = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('email', flat=True)
```

If you want to exclude empty email addresses, you can do it like this:

```
emails = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).exclude(email='').values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Comment: The list comprehension seems unnecessary, just use `values_list('email', flat=True)`.

Comment: Thanks! Updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can select email only from active users using this query.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

emails = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list('email', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```
email_list = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).values_list("email", flat=True)
```

See [the doc on `values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for more information.